# How to create singleton Class instance with constructor argument passed?

Tags: javascript, class, singleton

I have one file which is the class I wanna use as singleton

```
// class.js
class A {
  constructor() {}
  method x
}
export default new A();
```

And there are multiple files use it, which is fine, for example:

```
// use1
import a from 'class.js'
a.x()
```

```
// use2
import a from 'class.js'
a.x()
```

However, if I want to pass a argument to class when initialize the instance, how can I do it?

```
// class.js
class A {
  constructor(spec) {}
  method x
}
export default new A(spec);
```

```
// use1 need to do something like this
import spec from 'config.js'
import a(spec) from 'class.js' ?
a.x()
```

```
// use2
import spec from 'config.js'
import a(spec) from 'class.js'
a.x()
```

Also, it will be really redundant to pass `spec` to all the files.

Is there a way I can only initialize it once in one place but make it singleton?

Comment: As soon as you can pass different specs from different places, it's not longer a singleton. Don't use one, they're an antipattern anyway.

Comment: @Bergi I'm passing the same spec, just I need to pass it from a different file

Comment: You then should just import the spec into the file where you instantiate the singleton, be it `class.js` or a separate shared one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object instead of a class which literally a Singleton.

Comment: is there a ES6+ way to do it?

Comment: Objects are included in Es6+.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass an argument during an `import` statement. Why don't you just import the `spec` in class.js? That way each time you import `a`, it'll already be initiated with the desired constructor arguments.

```js
// class.js
import spec from 'config.js'

class A {
  constructor(spec) {}
  method x
}
export default new A(spec);
```

Comment: @Keming Why not? If you can import it to `use1` and `use2`, why can't you import it to `class.js`?

Comment: Cause class.js is actually a dependency library, I'll need to pass spec to it